# Do I need to wrap indexeddb transactions in a try/catch?

Tags: indexeddb

It looks like indexeddb has an onerror event, so do I need to wrap it in a try catch as well?

```js
try {
var reqst = window.db.transaction('xyz')
  .objectStore('xyz')
  .get(1234) 
reqst.onsuccess = success
reqst.onerror = error
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.stack)
}

function success(response) {}
function error(response) {}
```

The first scenario I can think of is if xyz doesn't exist, but that's the kind of error that would be caught while developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IDBDatabase.transaction` can synchronously throw an error in various situations](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbdatabase-transaction), so if you want to do something when one of those errors happens, you need a try/catch block.

Same thing with the other methods, like [`IDBTransaction.objectStore`](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbtransaction-objectstore), [`IDBObjectStore.get`](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbobjectstore-get), etc.

Comment: Thanks @dumbmatter! That page doesn't mention try catch though. Is a synchronous error different from an asynchronous one?  It looks like there are a number of things that occur _and then_ JavaScript will "Run the steps to asynchronously execute a request". So I suppose everything leading up to that needs to be in a try catch. Still though, it seems that it might be overkill. What example is there of a synchronous error that might occur in the field rather than being caught while developing?

Comment: By synchronous I mean "throw a  normal error that can be caught by try/catch". Asynchronous would be through the `onerror` event handler. So all the ones in my links that say stuff like "If mode parameter is not "readonly" or "readwrite", throw a TypeError", that is a synchronous error. Also, I believe QuotaExceededError only happens asynchronously, but I'm not 100% sure.